# Appcelerator Push from web

Tags: notifications, push, appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

from last Thursday I'm experiencing a problem in sending push notifications from the Appcelerator web page. The page hangs and the browser console gives me an error. Is it possible to solve the issue or does the solution work in progress?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I am also facing same problem, Push Notification page on Arrow DB show that my devices connected to Push, but when I click on Send Push Notification, then nothing is loading over there and there it shows 0 iOS devices and 0 Android devices...

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: The issue was solved. Now all works! Thanks a lot.